# Save *.mat files in a network location with extremely long names using Python

Tags: python, scipy

I have encountered a Problem with `scipy.io.savemat`. I am trying to save a `*.mat file` with extremely Long Name, but it is not able to create the file in the Directory. An example mat file Name would be:

> Ex:=
>   'MM01_MM02_MM03_hoch_MM03_runter_MM04_MM05_MP02_mr1_MP02_mr2_MR03_MR09_MR04_MR05_MR06_20170623_10-50-49.mat'

I use the `scipy.io.savemat` from the docs in this way:=

```
matPATH='V:\\Messdatenbank_Powertrain\\MESSDATENBANK_PER_CLICK\NVH_BILDVERGLEICHE_TMP\\MM01_MM02_MM03_hoch_MM03_runter_MM04_MM05_MP02_mr1_MP02_mr2_MR03_MR09_MR04_MR05_MR06_20170623_10-50-49\\'
stb_path=matPATH.split('\\')[-2]
fileName=str(stb_path+'_MM_MAX_COMPARE.mat')
sio.savemat(fileName,mm_stb_max_dict,long_field_names=True)
```

Can anyone suggest me how to save files with extremely Long names, i cannot find Information in scipy docs

[image]

Comment: Can you give the exact error message? And in this way the `pt` is only the filename, so the script will try to save it in the working directory. Is this the wanted behaviour?

Comment: @MaartenFabré, I read from Forums that Windows does not allow a file path to be more than 256 characters i think that is my Problem. i have checked the number of characters in the file path, it is greater than 256.